# Spring Cloud Config Server - Properties not being picked up

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

We are trying to add Spring Cloud Config Server to our project to externalize the configuration.

We have created a Config Server which connects to the Git repo and seems to be working correctly. However when we start a sample client it we get a message fetching config from server. Located environment but then a message to set a property which we have set in the corresponding yaml file in the git repo.

Config Server bootStrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configuration-service
server:
  port: 8888
```

Config Server application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  security:
    user:
      name: root
      password: M5awantk
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          clone-on-start: true
          uri: https://git.assembla.com/*********
          username: ***********
          password: ***********
```

Hitting http://localhost:8080/notification-service/default gives the following which is correct

```
{
 name: "notification-service",
 profiles: [
"default"
],
label: null,
version: "21ee5025b232b812e0e64387cd577eeda0351214",
state: null,
propertySources: [
{
name: "https://git.assembla.com/pins-configuration.git/notification-service.yml",
source: {
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding: true,
spring.application.name: "notification-service",
spring.zipkin.baseUrl: "http://localhost:9411/",
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true,
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: true,
server.port: 8091,
server.compression.enabled: true,
server.compression.min-response-size: 2048,
server.compression.mime-types: "application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/plain",
eureka.instance.hostname: "localhost",
eureka.instance.port: 8761,
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 3,
eureka.instance.instanceId: 
"${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}",
eureka.client.registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5,
eureka.client.instanceInfoReplicationIntervalSeconds: 5, 
eureka.client.initialInstanceInfoReplicationIntervalSeconds: 5,
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: 
"http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.port}/eureka/"  
}
}
]   
}
```

Client (named notification-service)

Client bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      username: root
      password: M5awantk
      name: notification-service
  application:
    name: notifcation-service
```

On staring the notification-service it seems to find the config service and the notification-service.yml as expected but then we get an error

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

Although we have the following in notification-service.yml and it shows when we hit  http://localhost:8080/notification-service/default

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding: true

Console output when starting notification-service

```
2020-03-24 18:26:03.046  INFO [notifcation-service,,,] 24238 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2020-03-24 18:26:04.847  INFO [notifcation-service,,,] 24238 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=notification-service, profiles=[default], label=null, version=21ee5025b232b812e0e64387cd577eeda0351214, state=null
2020-03-24 18:26:04.848  INFO [notifcation-service,,,] 24238 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: OriginTrackedCompositePropertySource {name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='configClient'}, OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='https://git.assembla.com/pins-configuration.git/notification-service.yml'}]}
2020-03-24 18:26:04.900  INFO [notifcation-service,,,] 24238 --- [           main] c.s.p.n.NotificationServiceApplication   : The following profiles are active: dev
2020-03-24 18:26:06.237  INFO [notifcation-service,,,] 24238 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-24 18:26:06.464  INFO [notifcation-service,,,] 24238 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 217ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-24 18:26:06.474  INFO [notifcation-service,,,] 24238 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-24 18:26:06.615  INFO [notifcation-service,,,] 24238 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 140ms. Found 21 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-24 18:26:06.616  WARN [notifcation-service,,,] 24238 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'jpaAuditingHandler' defined in null: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] for bean 'jpaAuditingHandler': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound.
2020-03-24 18:26:06.626  INFO [notifcation-service,,,] 24238 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-24 18:26:06.630 ERROR [notifcation-service,,,] 24238 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'jpaAuditingHandler' could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Not sure what we might be doing wrong.

EDIT: I have managed to get a very simple application working with just one property set in the corresponding application.yml.

Wondering if it is something to do with properties not being available in time, although from the console output that would not appear to be the case.

Comment: Hi [Ashley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2406072/ashley-callaghan), this post is almsot one year old, but my be it can't help you or someone else.
Read attentively the error-message: The bean **'jpaAuditingHandler'** could not be registered. A bean with that name **has already been defined** and overriding is disabled.
So, try to find out why you habe the **jpaAuditHandler** bean twice.